# GMail 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection

Tags: php, linux, dns, smtp, gmail

I'am trying to find out, why it fails to send mails from my server with GMail. For this I use SwiftMailer but I can enclose the problem to the following isolated code:

```
<?php

$sock = stream_socket_client('tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587', $errno, $errstr);
if (false == $sock) {
    die('error');
}
$server_response = fread($sock, 4096);
echo $server_response . PHP_EOL;
fclose($sock);
```

When I run this code on my local machine (Windows 10, XAMPP, PHP 5.6.24), the output is:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP qp16sm1358626ejb.89 - gsmtp
```

So 220 means everything is fine.

But when I run the exact same code on my server (Debian Jessie, PHP 5.6.38), the output is:

```
421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.
```

GMail's error reference https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730 doesn't give any advice for this error message.

I also tried this on the server console without PHP and it works fine too:

```
> nc smtp.gmail.com 587
$ 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP n11sm3188821wmi.15 - gsmtp
```

So I can delimit the problem

- It has nothing to do with any security settings of my GMail account (because no authentification is sent at this point)
- My server is not blacklisted on GMail (because the `nc` command works fine)

Are there any settings of the php.ini that can cause this error?

**UPDATE**

Just for fun I set up a simple TCP server on port 587 on another machine and display the IP address of any connected client.
There is no different if I use the above PHP client code or connecting via `nc` command.
I don't know what could be the different for the GMail's SMTP server while conneting via the client PHP code and the `nc` command.

**UPDATE 2**

While enabling verbose mode in the `nc` command, could `DNS fwd/rev mismatch` be a problem?

```
> nc -v smtp.gmail.com 587
$ DNS fwd/rev mismatch: smtp.gmail.com != wr-in-f109.1e100.net
$ smtp.gmail.com [108.177.15.109] 587 (submission) open
$ 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z15sm4348737wrn.89 - gsmtp
```

**UPDATE 3**

Run the above code with

```
$sock = stream_socket_client('tcp://wr-in-f109.1e100.net:587', $errno, $errstr);
```

It works, it responses with 220. But the problem is, SwiftMailer try to establish TLS security after with `stream_socket_enable_crypto()` and this fails with

```
Peer certificate CN=`smtp.gmail.com' did not match expected CN=`wr-in-f109.1e100.net'
```

**UPDATE 4**

It's getting me crazy. When I use Python's TCP sockets to connect to smtp.gmail.com, GMail responses with 220:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))
data = s.recv(4096)
s.close()

print data
```

Output:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP p6sm8392243wmg.0 - gsmtp
```

What is the difference between Python's sockets and PHP's stream_socket_client?

**Edit**:
The same behavior with PHP's non-streaming socket function:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if(!is_resource($socket)) onSocketFailure("Failed to create socket");
socket_connect($socket, "smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        or onSocketFailure("Failed to connect", $socket);

$line = socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

var_dump($line);
socket_close($socket);
```

**UPDATE 5**

Now I think it is a problem with IPv6. I'am not a big C programmer but I tried to understand the PHP's implementation.

Have a look at

- [xp_socket.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/xp_socket.c#L782) the function `php_tcp_sockop_connect` uses `php_network_connect_socket_to_host`
- [network.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/network.c#L767) which is implemented here
- It use `php_network_getaddresses`
- and this function use `getaddrinfo`

`php_network_connect_socket_to_host` iterates of the list of host addresses and tries to connect to it. If its success, it stops with looping.

I don't tried it out with C but I think the following Python code does the same:

```
import socket
print socket.getaddrinfo("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
```

Which prints

```
[
 (10, 1, 6, '', ('2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d', 587, 0, 0)),
 (10, 2, 17, '', ('2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d', 587, 0, 0)),
 (10, 3, 0, '', ('2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d', 587, 0, 0)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('108.177.15.109', 587)),
 (2, 2, 17, '', ('108.177.15.109', 587)),
 (2, 3, 0, '', ('108.177.15.109', 587))
]
```

(I formatted the line for better reading)

As you can see, there are three IPv6 addresses on the top of the list and `php_network_connect_socket_to_host` try these IPv6 adresses first before it comes to the IPv4 addresses.

So what happens when I try to connect directly to the first IPv6 address?

```
<?php

$sock = stream_socket_client('tcp://[2a00:1450:400c:c02::6c]:587', $errno, $errstr);
if (false == $sock) {
    die('error');
}
$server_response = fread($sock, 4096);
echo $server_response . PHP_EOL;
fclose($sock);
```

The output is:

```
421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.
```

This SO question is related to this observation: [Why I can't send emails using smtp.gmail.com:587 on ipv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160968/why-i-cant-send-emails-using-smtp-gmail-com587-on-ipv6)

Answer (score 8):

After finding out, that the error message happens when the IPv6 address is used the hack is to prefer the IPv4 address.

Acording to https://serverfault.com/questions/511237/linux-block-ipv6-for-certain-applications-hostnames#answer-514397 the easiest way was to put the following line to `etc/hosts`:

```
108.177.15.109 smtp.gmail.com
```

The drawback of this solution is the static IP address. `smtp.gmail.com` might change the IP address. This is the cause why I don't mark this answer as accepted.

I don't know if its possible to configure [`/etc/gai.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/gai.conf) to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 for only `smtp.gmail.com`.

This article might be interesting to get a detailed look, how getaddrinfo works: https://jameshfisher.com/2018/02/03/what-does-getaddrinfo-do/

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it worked for me!!! Even google couldn't help me, they keep proposing to change account settings.

Comment: Your welcome :) The message `421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.` is the greeting that is send directly after connecting. At this point, GMail doesn't know anything about the user. Account settings are useless for this problem.