# Django: Force ipv4 for EMAIL_HOST? (GMail: 421, '4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.')

Tags: python, django, ipv4

If I try to send a mails with Django via settings.EMAIL_HOST, I get this error:

> (421, '4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.')

I found a work-around ([GMail 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375834/gmail-421-4-7-0-try-again-later-closing-connection))

It works if I use a IPv4 connection (and not IPV6).

`EMAIL_HOST = '64.233.184.108'`

But this is just a work-around, I would like to have a solution. Because if google changes the IP of the smtp servers, my solution will fail.

How can I tell Django or Python to use IPv4 when I use this?

`EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'`

By default my system uses ipv6, and then Google thinks I am a spammer and blocks me with "(421, '4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.')"

Comment: Google might be one of the worst choices for a mail server in Django.

Comment: @KlausD. Please tell me an alternative to gmail. It works fine (except above error) and is free. This is just a non-profit hobby project.

Comment: *"By default my system uses ipv6, and then Google thinks I am a spammer and blocks me"*. Where does this spammer assumption come from? Secondly, unlike HTTP, SMTP 4xx errors are not fatal. It even says so. You'll have to resend. What's more likely is that your IPv6 reverse does not resolve. I vaguely remember reading years ago that reverse DNS is a requirement for IPV6 connections. Either way, just resend or better, use a proper sendmail/postfix local install so you don't have to queue yourself.

Comment: @Melvyn thank you for pointing me into the right direction! Yes, I think I only added the ipv4 address to my DNS config, not the ipv6. I guess that's the reason why I get rejected.

Comment: @Melvyn if you write your comment as answer, then I can up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My IPv6 reverse DNS did not resolve. That was the problem.

After adding my ipv6 address to the DNS things worked.

Big "Thank you!" to @Melvyn!